# I'm making my first Python program using Python 3 but for some reason it gives me an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication

I wanted to test my program in the middle of writing it, but it won't start for some reason

CODE:

```
def main():
    menu()
def menu():
    print("1.Login\n2.Register\n\n1.Help")
    input = int(input("Enter the corresponding number to the action you would like executed: "))
    if input==3:
        help()
    if input==2:
        register()
    if input==1:
        login()

def help():
    print("\nIf you enter the number ONE (1) You will be prompted to login to the system\nIf you enter the number TWO (2) you will be prompted to register, so you can login")

def register():
    usernameR = input("Enter your username: ")
    with open("usernamesR.txt","wt") as output:
        output.write(usernameR)
    print("Your username is: "+usernameR)
    passwordR = str(input("\nEnter your password: "))
    with open("passwordsR.txt","wt") as output:
        output.write(passwordR)
    print("Your password is: "+passwordR)

def login():
    print("")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

This is the error I got:

1.Login

Traceback (most recent call last):

2.Register

File "C:/Users/Joseph/PycharmProjects/LearningPython/Login_System.py", line    30, in 
   main()

1.Help

File "C:/Users/Joseph/PycharmProjects/LearningPython/Login_System.py", line 2, in main

menu()

File "C:/Users/Joseph/PycharmProjects/LearningPython/Login_System.py", line 5, in menu
    input = int(input("Enter the corresponding number to the action you would like executed: "))

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'input' referenced before assignment

Comment: it is raw_input,
**input = int(raw_input("Enter the corresponding number to the action you would like executed: "))**
use raw_input where ever u need a user input!!

Comment: For python3, `input` is actually correct in this case: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input()` ins in build function,

In code you give **variable** name as `input`, give **different variable name**.

```
def menu():
    print("1.Login\n2.Register\n\n1.Help")
    input = int(input("Enter the corresponding number to the action you would like executed: "))
    # ^^^^
```

Comment: Well thanks you man, the error makes it kind of confusing to understand,

Answer (score 0):

Your variable name `input` clashes with the built-in method `input`. The compiler is getting confused, thinking that the `input()` call is calling your locally-bound variable, and then complaining that you haven't defined it yet. Changing your variable name to `user_input` should fix this.